# Send Whatsapp message programatically without clicking send

Tags: android, whatsapp

I have a code to send text and picture images to spedific Whatsapp contact programatically.
Yet, the user is prompted to click the send button from within Whatsapp.
Is there a way to execute the sending without the automatic loading of the Whatsapp contact chat then manually click the send button ?
thanks

Code to send image:

```
public void sendWhatsappPictureToContact(String phoneNo, Bitmap bitmap, String message) {
try {
Uri imageUri = getImageToShare(bitmap);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
intent.putExtra("jid", phoneNo + "@s.whatsapp.net");
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("SHARE", "Exception occured sharing file", e);
Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Code to send text:

```
private void sendWhatsappTextToContact(String phoneNo, String message) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phoneNo + "&text=" + message;
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
intent.setPackage(packageName);
try {
    startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error Message");
    }
}
```